# How to change from Model-first to Code-First in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had started a project with Model-First, with one existing base, now I need to change to code-first to change some specifics things in FK´s. 
  So How I keep the classes and change to code-first? It´s even possible?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already generated your database from your model, you can use the "Reverse Engineer Code First" feature of [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d). This will generate both your POCO model classes and Fluent API mapping classes for you.

Answer (score 1):

I did this myself fairly recently. The expressive powers of Model-First and Code-First are identical. If you write your Code-First classes such that the property names and types match what you had in your Model-First types, the transition should be very easy.

For example, if you have a Model-First model `Item` with `int ID` key, `string Name`, and `int ListID` foreign key, with `List List` navigation property, you can make the Code-First class as follows.

```
class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ListID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ListID")]
    public virtual List List { get; set; }        
}
```

All of your old code that uses `Item` should likely remain working.